# Why Auth::user() return null in routes of a custom Service Provider?

Tags: laravel, authentication, view, routes, service-provider

I'm making a new Service called `Factures` in `App\Services\Factures`. 
I created the `\App\Services\Factures\FacturesServiceProvider`:

```php
public function register() {
    $this->app->bind('factures', function ($app) {
        return new Facture;
    });
}

public function boot() {
    // laod Routes
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ .'/Http/routes.php');

    // load Views
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'factures');
}
```

I registered my provider everything works fine expect the `Auth::user()` in returns me  `null` in the views and the `routes.php`.

How can I get access to the Auth() in custom service?

Comment: Is the session middleware added in your Kernel file in the web middleware array? Is the user logged in?

Comment: Yes, all other routes from routes/web.php workes fine and I can access the Auth(). 
Only in the new service I can't access the Auth()

Answer (score 1):

This post resolved my problem: [User Auth not persisting within Laravel package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383911/user-auth-not-persisting-within-laravel-package)

I figure out that Laravel  apply to the default routes/web.php file a middleware called 'web' And doesn't apply this group to external package routes loaded via service provider's.

So my routes in the custom file should be in `web` middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('testing-services', function(){
        dd(Auth::user());
        // output is valid
    });
});
```