# Using Laravel and Ajax and a custom package controller, how to login and redirect a user with ajax

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-302

I have a pretty base Laravel 9 install.

I wrote a custom package that is installed that provides a route and a controller action. The controller action is designed to Login a user via ajax, and return a response that tells the front end where to redirect the now logged-in user.

```
/**
 * CustomLogin
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return string A json response with either success or fail
 */
public function customLogin(Request $request){

    // Do some other things to make sure this is ok
        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            'something_cool' => $request->address
        ]);

        Auth::login($user);


        return response()
            ->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Successfully Login',
                'url' => route('dashboard')
            ], 200);        
}
```

This all works, I have tested it by logging that the Auth::login($user) works.  The response works as well.  But then in my JS:

```
axios.post('/custom-login', {
                address: address,
                proof: response.proof,
                signedMessage: response.signedMessage
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                window.location.href = response.data.url;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                //this.errorHandle('fail', 'Something went wrong.')
            });
```

The response.data.url is just a simple route to the default Laravel dashboard.

There is also a session file created in storage\framework\sessions.

My /dashboard route is:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
  return view('dashboard');
})->middleware('auth')->name('dashboard');
```

I did test this as just a controller action in App\Http\Controllers and it worked fine. But somehow in the custom package, the login works and then the redirect to the /dashboard returns a HTTP 302.

How can I log a user in from a custom package controller and have it stick?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383911/user-auth-not-persisting-within-laravel-package this solved my issue, but I'd love to hear more about why.